# Error in handling command line arguments in C

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to write a C code that will take three arguments from the command line in the form of `{num1} {operator} {num2}`. It is working fine in case of all operator symbols other than `*`.

This is the code to verify this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    printf("%d\n", argc);
}
```

I am compiling this as `gcc test.c -o test`.

Then when I run it using `./test 5 + 9`, it gives the expected output `4`. But then when I run `./test 5 * 9`, it gives `25` as output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `argc` is the number of arguments.

Comment: Yes I know that, was just confused regarding getting `*` as a command line argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` is expanded by the shell into a list of all files in the current directory. If you don't want shell-expansion you need to (single) quote the argument:

```
./test 5 '*' 9
```

Comment: Thanks! This didn't come across at all in my mind. Just out of curiosity, is there any way to achieve what I initially wanted, not giving the (single) quotes around *?

Comment: @AbhisekChaudhuri Unfortinately no, not in your program anyway.